# legendItemClick not getting triggred after changing chart type

Tags: highcharts

I have a legendItemClick event in my highstock chart. It opens a jQuery Dialog when when i click a legend and grabs current series id, type, yAxis etc. This part is working fine.
I am not able to call my legend item click for the second time if i change my chart type dynamically. though it works fine if i change just the chart axis dynamically.

legend item click code:

```
plotOptions: {
line: {
events: { checkboxClick: function () {
alert("checkbox clicked");
},
legendItemClick: function () {
console.log("In legend item click");
console.log(this);
//event.preventDefault();
$("#dialog")
.dialog("open");
$("#legendTable")
.html("");
$('#legendTable')
.append("<tr>"
+"<td>Axis</td><td><select onchange=\"updateSeries("+this.index+")\" id=\"legendAxis\""
+" name=\"legendAxis\"><option value=\"0\">1</option><option"
+" value=\"1\">2</option><option value=\"2\">3</option></select></td>"
+"<td>Type</td><td><select onchange=\"updateSeries("+this.index+")\" id=\"legendType\""
+" name=\"legendType\"><option value=\"line\">Line</option><option"
+" value=\"column\">Column</option><option value=\"area\">Area</option>"
+"<option value=\"bar\">Bar</option>"
+"<option value=\"spline\">Spline</option>"
+"<option value=\"areaspline\">Area Spline</option>"
+"</select></td>"
+"</tr>");
$("#legendAxis").val(this.userOptions.yAxis);
$("#legendType").val(this.userOptions.type);
return false;
}
}
}
}
```

Update Series Code:

```
function updateSeries(id) {
console.log("in update");
console.log($("#legendAxis")
.val());
console.log($("#legendType")
.val());
var chart = $('#container')
.highcharts();
chart.series[id].update({
type: $("#legendType")
.val(),
yAxis: parseInt($("#legendAxis")
.val())
});
return;
};
```

Dialog Box Code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Update Series">
<table id="legendTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using line instead of series in below code.
previous:

```
plotOptions: {
line: {
events: { checkboxClick: function () {
alert("checkbox clicked");
},
```

instead:

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
events: { checkboxClick: function () {
alert("checkbox clicked");
},
```